# Draw a line in OpenCV does not work

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, drawing, line

When I run this code which is supposed to draw a line on a black surface, I do not get any error messages but nothing is shown either. What's wrong ?

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

class DessinerLigne:
    def dessinerLigne(self):
        # Create a black image
        self.img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)

        # Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
        self.img=cv2.line(self.img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)

        # If q is pressed then exit program
        self.k=cv2.waitKey(0)
        if self.k==ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__=="__main__":
    DL=DessinerLigne()
    DL.dessinerLigne()
```

Comment: how do you display images in python? I guess there's a `cv2.imshow("windowname", self.img)` or something similar missing before the `waitKey`?

Comment: above code works with opencv3.0 only, the 2.4 version does not return an image from cv2.line() [ and right, lacking imshow() you won't see anything]

Comment: @berak can I use OpenCV3.0 with Python 2.7.9 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=line#cv2.line), you can see cv2.line() returns nothing, but operates in-place.

So your code can be

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

class DessinerLigne:
    def dessinerLigne(self):
        # Create a black image
        self.img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)

        # Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
        cv2.line(self.img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
        cv2.imshow("Image", self.img)
        # If q is pressed then exit program
        self.k=cv2.waitKey(0)
        if self.k==ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__=="__main__":
    DL=DessinerLigne()
    DL.dessinerLigne()
```